# MobileFirst CLI - edit/build/test cycle

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

One thing I really like about the later version of Worklight/MobileFirst Studio is the faster edit/test cycle when working in the Mobile Browser Simulator: just edit, save, click Go/Refresh; no need to build/deploy.

When using CLI (6.3.0.00.20141111-1216) this does not seem to be the case. Seems like I need to do

```
mfp build; mfp deploy;
```

After every edit. Am I missing a trick?

Right now I'm thinking I need to revert to my old practice of setting up a web-server to serve directly from my product folder, which is not ideal because I then need to mock up the WL.* APIs I use.

Comment: At the current time, this is a limitation of the CLI, based on the use of a standalone MFP Server.  Within Studio, some special tricks are being played, to just updated modified files. We are working to resolve this in the CLI and perform similar per file deployments, but we're not there yet.  In the interim, I encourage you to view Justin Berstler's video on using the CLI with Grunt.  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/videos/integrating-ibm-mobilefirst-cli-grunt-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information from Karl Bishop:

At the current time, this is a limitation of the CLI, based on the use of a standalone MFP Server. Within Studio, some special tricks are being played, to just updated modified files. We are working to resolve this in the CLI and perform similar per file deployments, but we're not there yet. In the interim, I encourage you to view [Justin Berstler's video](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/videos/) on using the CLI with Grunt.